# Swift local vs global scope arrays

Tags: arrays, performance, swift

That the Swift beta isn't a winner in the area of array performance has been pointed out over and over again in this forum.

But did anyone notice that Swift is completely lost when it comes to handling global declared arrays?

Take a look at the code snippet underneath. The repsonse times I measured are downright desastrous. I can't possible think of a scenario that causes this ridiculous results and makes my Macbook 2014 processor run at full speed.

Am I missing something or is there some explanation? Please reasure me.

```
let maxElements = 1000000;
.   
.      
.
func printElapsedTime(startTime: NSDate, message: String) {
  let endTime = NSDate();
  println(message + ": " + NSString(format:"%.6f", endTime.timeIntervalSinceDate(startTime)) + " sec");
}

func benchMark1() {
  var localArray = Array(count:maxElements, repeatedValue:String());

  let someString = "Percy Jackson - The Titan's Curse";
  var anotherString: String;

  var startTime = NSDate();
  for i in 0..<maxElements {
    localArray[i] = someString;
  }
  printElapsedTime(startTime, message: "Elapsed time for creating and altering a local array");

  startTime = NSDate();
  for i in 10..<20 {
    anotherString = localArray[i];
  }
  printElapsedTime(startTime, message: "Elapsed time accessing 10 elements of the local array");
}
// Elapsed time for creating and altering a local array: 2.637573 sec
// Elapsed time for read accessing 10 elements of the local array: 0.000039 sec

func benchMark2() {

  var localArray = Array(count:maxElements, repeatedValue:String());
  let someString = "Percy Jackson - The Titan's Curse";
  var anotherString: String;

  var startTime = NSDate();
  for i in 0..<maxElements {
    localArray[i] = someString;
  }
  self.globalArray = localArray;
  printElapsedTime(startTime, message: "Elapsed time for creating/altering a local array and copy it into a global array");

  startTime = NSDate();
  for i in 10..<20 {
    anotherString = globalArray[i];
  }
  printElapsedTime(startTime, message: "Elapsed time accessing 10 elements of the global array");
}
// Elapsed time for creating/altering a local array and copy it into a global array: 9.570817 sec
// Elapsed time read accessing 10 elements of the global array: 143.937524 sec !!!!
```

Comment: I have no idea what's wrong with your setup, the timings I get are nothing like yours (for 1000 items). Elapsed time for creating and altering a local array: 2.060414 sec
Elapsed time accessing 10 elements of the local array: 0.021805 sec
Elapsed time for creating/altering a local array and copy it into a global array: 2.112086 sec
Elapsed time accessing 10 elements of the global array: 0.021161 sec. That being said, it's very much too early to evaluate the language performance, they are probably still using very naive implementations to be able to change stuff easily.

Comment: Nothing wrong with my setup Fabrice, except my backlog in Beta version. I’ve just installed XCode 6 Beta-5 and found similar results as your benchmarks, even slightly better. Try to run them with Beta-4 when it is still there and you’ll see my point.
“Too early to judge performance? Naive implementation?” I don’t think so. A lot of the beta testing jobs have to do with performance, especially when dealing with a new language. Check the forum!

Comment: And then again, array-handling consists of well known techniques, in essence allocation of lumps of consecutive space on stack or heap and in the case of items of variable size, building an index for easy access. For items of fixed size, the offset easily can be calculated hence no need for an index. It looks like the Swift developers deliberately built in some heavy duty loops, since my processor was moaning as if it had to calculate the last few digits of pi, just before this number slides into infinity.

Comment: By taking away this superfluous workload, the guys can show off with having performed a marvelous optimization job.
But we aren’t there yet. Compare Swift array performance against objective-c. Poor, but there’s hope for a good final product as you pointed out. But now, try to create the global array and fill it with data straight away, so without the trick of an interim local array. This takes ages! Another implementation issue?

Comment: I wasn't thinking about the Array implementation, I was thinking about how the variables or instance properties are accessed and stored. I do not think there is much difference between an Array (local) and another Array (in an instance)... Dynamic is now partially implemented, but using the objc runtime. They already said this will change to something better... Naive implementation, I maintain my position.

Comment: Fabrice, I agree there isn't much difference between local and global declared array's. There shouldn't be, since the only distinction is a set of scope rules. I'm anxious to learn about the workout of a practical meant access scenario for variables or properties that causes our processors to run like they want to beat the Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy champ. Anyway, we'll soon see the final outcome I suppose, as of the intended Yosemity release with XCode 6 in October. "..using the objc runtime. They already said this will change to something better.." I didn't get that info. Any links?